# When changing build target to release in Visual Studio, thousands of errors appear

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I setup a simple Empty Project on Visual Studio 2022. I attached some GLFW / Glad sources to it so that I could do a basic rendering project.

I've been editing it for around two days with no issues. It runs fine.

I went to build it and noticed the debug version builds the debug console and everything into the EXE, which I didn't want.

I tried to do a release version instead, and when I switch to release, suddenly all of my `include`s in my code start pushing like 100 errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA1xB.png)

When I fix all the include errors (Using VS's recommended fix tool), the errors go away, but then when I try to build, thousands of more errors appear, and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

It's at a point right now where I can only use the debug version with the console popup, which is really irritating, considering I'm developing a desktop application. I cant have these debug tools popping up while I'm trying to use a piece of software.

My full code so far is right here: https://github.com/ArctanStudios/GLSL-Bay

I've done some searching on my own but I haven't found anything helpful.

When asking people on other sites I was told that I just "screwed something up" providing absolutely zero help or an explanation as to what I could do to fix this issue. Id appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Just a guess, have you configured the release with the libraries in the right order?

Comment: You seemed to configure the include and library directories and dependency libs in the Debug config only. You might forgot to do it for the Release or All configs.

Comment: I dont know how to do it for release... I just set the libraries at the start, I didnt know there was a separate set of debug vs release libraries

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the Document: [Set debug and release configurations in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-debug-and-release-configurations?view=vs-2022).

Visual Studio projects have separate release and debug configurations for your program.

Comment: Yeah I unfortunately only realized this too late. I wound up just restarting the whole project and its all working now